# For an $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$, find a factorization of the form $A = L\hat{U}$ ...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

For an $n$ by $n$ matrix $A$, find a factorization of the form $A = L\hat{U}$ where $L$ is a lower triangular matrix and for some permutation matrix, $P$ the matrix $P\hat{U}$ is upper triangular with 1's on the diagonal.

For example given matrix $A = $
\begin{bmatrix} 
0&1&1\\
0&-2&1\\
-2&1&1
\end{bmatrix}

I am able to get to this point:

$$A = L_5 P_5D^{-1}DU_5$$ where

$$L_5 = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{2}&0&0\\-1&-2&0\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$P_5 = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1&0\\0&0&1\\1&0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$U_5 = \begin{bmatrix} -2&1&1\\0&2&2\\0&0&\frac{-3}{2} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$D = Diag\bigg(\frac{-1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{-2}{3}\bigg)$$
$$D^{-1} = Diag\bigg(-2, 2, \frac{-3}{2}\bigg)$$

It took a lot of computation for me to even get to this point but I don't know how to proceed. I am not sure if there is a very simple clever way to do this.

Comment: Hi, but $\hat{U}$ is not necessarily upper triangular. We just know that there exists a P such that P$\hat{U}$ is upper triangular. The question asks to find a decomposition of the form A = L$\hat{U}$, where P is a permutation matrix such that P$\hat{U}$ is upper triangular.

Comment: Maybe we can solve for all permutations of the rows of $\hat{U}$? and pick a solution and its corresponding $P$?